# Heroku - SSL off error - after previously working perfectly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

After having everything working on my Heroku app for months, I started getting this error yesterday:

no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "xxxxx", database "xxxxz", SSL off"

I've only been working on the client side and haven't changed anything on the server, so I don't know what could be going on.

server package.json

```
  {
    "name": "spiral-server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha --require test/setup.js",
        "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
        "start": "node src/server.js",
        "migrate": "postgrator --config postgrator-config.js",
        "migrate:test": "env NODE_ENV=test npm run migrate",
        "migrate:production": "env SSL=true DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) npm run migrate",
        "predeploy": "npm audit",
        "deploy": "git push heroku master",
        "postdeploy": "npm run migrate:production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.14.1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "helmet": "^4.1.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "knex": "^0.21.5",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "pg": "^8.3.3",
        "postgrator": "^4.0.1",
        "postgrator-cli": "^3.2.0",
        "xss": "^1.0.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "mocha": "^8.1.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "supertest": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to start debugging, when I already had it working perfectly.

The only change I might have made was to the GitHub repo name (I changed a few repo names, and not sure if I changed this one or not)

All my other work has been on the client which is a React app hosted on Vercel.

I get the pg error when I query from localhost, Vercel, or Postman.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error is pretty specific,  the `pg_hba.conf` for the instance does not contain an entry for the connection being requested. So either: 1) The `pg_hba.conf` file has been changed 2) The connection has changed for one or more of the parameters listed in the error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - thanks, so is the pg_hba.conf supplied by Heroku, or do I have direct access to edit that somewhere (I don't see it in my express app). When you say the connection has changed for one of the paramaters, do you mean the host, user or database may be incorrect somehow?

Comment: Best guess is it is this: `SSL off`. I'm not that familiar with Heroku, but I do believe it requires `SSL` connections. I'm going to say that at least one of your clients is attempting a non-SSL connection. You probably should go back over the changes you made client side and see if any relate to connection properties and/or Postgres diver changes.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - appreciate it, I've tried reverting changes to a previous commit and the error still persists. It also persists from Postman, so doesn't that mean it's likely not the React client?

Comment: I'm in the middle of a job search with a few people cloning the repository daily. I don't want to sound conspiratorial, but is it possible someone 'hacked' me or did something on their end?

Comment: Does the un-anonymized connection: `host "x.x.x.x", user "xxxxx", database "xxxxz",` look familiar? Where is the error showing up?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - honestly it doesn't look familiar. It looks strange, but I forgot exactly what I had it as before.

Comment: Where is the error showing up?

Comment: The error is showing up whenever I try to make a GET or POST request from a client.. so when I try to login with credentials from my react app its returned as an error to the console. With postman I'm getting it in the response body.

Comment: I changed my  PGSSLMODE config var to no-verify which looks like it worked. Not sure if that's a best practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

Add a new `PGSSLMODE` env variable with `require` as value under your app settings in Heroku.

Then restart your dyno...
`heroku ps:restart`

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but now I'm getting self signed certificate error.